# Href link with php value

Tags: php, href

i am having  a link like below

```
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=Reading+Facebook share, Yahoo Buzz and Tweet this buttons for Blogger blogs+http://www.didiknow.com');">Tweet this</a>
```

i want to insert a php variable value inside for the status thing
like

```
          <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=$markme_ddesc');">Tweet this</a>
```

how to do so?? please help me..

Answer (score 2):

you can just echo it in there?

```
<?= $markme_ddesc ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways, for example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=<?=$markme_ddesc?>">Tweet this</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=<?php print($markme_ddesc);?>">Tweet this</a>
```

or (in case you are within the  tags)

```
print("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=$markme_ddesc\">Tweet this</a>");
```

Comment: Can you say how they didn't work? Have you defined the $markme_ddesc variable and actually have a working php script?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/tc/public_html/td/plugins/content/bookmarker.php on line 114

Comment: And i think u didnt give ) and close quotes it wont work.. I am having the PHP variable there..

Comment: Both work for me in my testing. Make sure you don't have the examples within <?php .. ?> tags!

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE THIS

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=<?=$markme_ddesc?>">Tweet this</a>

note: status=<?=$markme_ddesc?>
```